# EC2 security group concern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

**EC2 --> RDS:**

**RDS (DB Engine):** I have inbound and outbound open on port 3306 for the web server's security group.

**EC2 (Web Server):** I have inbound open for 80, 443 and 22(myIP). Outbound is open for 80,443 and 3306, and it needs all traffic as well to function properly.

My question is about the outbound rules of my web server. Why do I need all traffic to be open? Does this have any security concern?

Comment: What doesn't function properly if the EC2 instance does not have all outbound traffic open?

Comment: I remember I had ajax problems for login, and a lot of weird CSS malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

Some people lock down outbound to prevent against data loss. It works better for immutable architecture since you've removed the ability to update packages from public sources.

Obviously you can choose your own security profile; generally speaking I consider this the levels of security:

1. Port 22 open to the world
2. Port 22 access by white listed IPs
3. Bastion host with white listed IPs
4. VPN (from here down, all using VPN)
5. Private IPs + NAT
6. Proxies server outbound access

That's my ec2 security maturity model. I'm sure I missed some- feel free to comment below.

Comment: tnx for your comment tedder, How do I go about to adding a VPN connection to my VPC? Is that useful when EC2 and RDS are both in the same VPC?

Comment: VPN is great. It takes some work to set up, though. [Here's one walkthrough](http://envyandroid.com/setup-free-private-vpn-on-amazon-ec2/); it was a few days of work to get it set up precisely how I needed for my team.

Answer (score 0):

The security group outbound rules let you to specify  "destination", not source. Basically you don't need to worry being attack by Denial of Server through the outbound rules.

On the other hand, unless your Web server need to connect out to Internet without restriction, then you set 80+443 destination to 0.0.0.0/0.

Otherwise , if your web server only need to connect to OS repositories for security update (e.g. ubuntu, apache,etc), then you can explicitly specify the repositories IP address instead of using 0.0.0.0/0.

Other than that, there is little risk.  Unless you load something that render webpage, e.g. load web browser in the web server that read random webpage, then it make you susceptible to browser/java engine/rendering engine exploit : if exploit can execute something like ssh reverse tunnel, then there is possibilities that attacker may gain access to your web server.

Comment: tnx for the info, I have a follow-up question: I have all traffic open on my network ACL. Should I make the ACL rules identical to web server security group?

Comment: You may have a route table that propagate connection among subnet., NACL is just fine grain firewall AMONG your VPC subnets to restrict some default routing connection among subnet,  I wouldn't bother NACL  unless I have many instances and I don't want some instance too see each other.